Is there any way to hide queryparams in angular v12?
i dont want user to see the queryparams
this.router.navigate([/cbam-tools/stepper/update/${runID}],{ queryParams: { productID: record.productID} });
The better way would be if  someone can help how to pass data dynamically from one page to another without using params and queryparams , i am familiar with parent child relation but that won't work in the current scenerio


Store the values in a service and access them
Use a BehaviourSubject set the value and navigate, then subscribe to the BehaviourSubject and get the values.
Use some state management like ngrx.

Also be aware that the values in the URL has the advantage that when the page is refreshed the state is maintained, since the URL contains the data, but that is not the case of the above three suggestions!
Store the data in localstorage and access it, this does not have the above problem, but it's a rarely used solution and I would not recommend this!
